# hyperref + glossaries + \DeclareMathOperator + latex + dvips = math italics instead of math upright

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, glossaries, italic, dvi-mode

Let's save the input (which I believe to respesent a minimal or at least a rather small working example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[makeindex,nomain]{glossaries}%%% glossaries according to its documentation should be loaded after hyperref.
\DeclareMathOperator{\domain}{\gls{not:domain}} %%% the domain of a map
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{not:domain}{type=notation, name={\(\mathrm{dom}\)}, text={dom}, sort={functionDomain}, description={The domain of a function}}
\begin{document}
\(\domain f\)
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

in the file `mwe.tex`.  Running

```
pdflatex mwe && makeindex -s mwe.ist -t mwe.nlg -o mwe.not mwe.ntn && pdflatex mwe
```

results in

[image: the PDF output of a pdflatex-makeindex loop]

Notice that the first occurrence of “dom” is upright.

Feeding the same input to

```
latex mwe && makeindex -s mwe.ist -t mwe.nlg -o mwe.not mwe.ntn && latex mwe && dvips mwe
```

results in the following DVI output:

[image: the DVI output of a latex-makeindex loop]

Notice that the first occurrence of “dom” is italic.

In the Postscript output the first occurrence of “dom” is italic as well:

[image: PS output of a latex-makeindex loop followed by dvips]

Clearly (cf. page 40 of “[A Primer of Mathematical Writing](https://books.google.de/books?id=EYHFObaUIdIC)” by Steve G. Krantz, also cf. page 43 of the [second edition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04888.pdf)), such a difference in formatting between the PDF and the PS files (upright vs. italic) is wrong™, for a sufficiently inclusive definition of wrong™.  In my own experience, I believe the upright version to be expected and the italic version to be unexpected and requiring a bugfix.

So,

1. Who is the culprit?
2. What to do to fix the problem?

Comment: You are correct that the `\mathrm` form is the correct one.  But I am sorry to have to tell you that the book you cite by Krantz should not be trusted for correct LaTeX input, or at least the use of "best practices".  (I was a member of the TeXnical support crew of the publisher, and did read, and correct, several chapters explicitly about LaTeX before publication, but didn't have the chance to read the rest until it was in print.)  Advice about mathematical notation and conventions is solid, but not the LaTeX mechanics.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! I recall that I read about the abuse of “clearly” originally elsewhere, probably in some lecture notes of Hannah/Holger Bast, but I failed to find these notes now. If you have an earlier reference (perhaps, going back to Hardy and Littlewood?), I'd be glad to have it, or simply edit the question yourself.

Comment: I didn't trace it all but `text={\mathrm{dom}}` looks like it works

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know how to get a roman `dom` in this situation, but you won't find it in Krantz.  What I would try is (1) put `\protect` before `\mathrm` in the glossary entry, or (2) define `\Dom` separately (using an uppercase name to avoid possible conflict with already defined `\dom`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to glossaries, but to the way links are build on the dvips route: in this case hyperref surrounds the link text with a box and switches back to math inside the box.

You will have to add the `\mathrm` inside the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\(\mathrm{\href{xxx}{dom}}\quad \mathrm{\href{xxx}{\mathrm{dom}}}\)

\end{document}
```

### output with pdftex

[image]

### output with dvips

[image]

Comment: Thanks! (1) Then, the outer `\mathrm` seems unnecessary in DVI mode. In this particular case of the domain of a map, instead of `\DeclareMathOperator{\domain}{\gls{not:domain}}` something weaker could be used that only sets the horizontal distance to the following symbol properly (as opposed to setting both the distance and the font). Do you know what this could be? I'd wrap it then into `\ifpdf … \else … \fi` and, pragmatically, consider myself done. (2) Can this be automatized/resolved already on the level of hyperref? Should I bother the maintainer?

Comment: sorry I don't quite get what your mean, `text={\mathrm{dom}}` as suggested by David should be fine. And no, hyperref can't insert a \mathrm automatically, it can't know what the content is.

Comment: I mean that doing mathrm twice (outside of href and inside or href, as in your `\mathrm{\href{xxx}{\mathrm{dom}}}` seems like doing unnecessary work, doesn't it? The outer `\mathrm` seems to be issued by `\DeclareMathOperator`, so, potentially, one could do something more lightweight instead of `\DeclareMathOperator` in the DVI mode. I think of `\newcommand{\domain}{\mathop{\gls{not:domain}}}` with `text={\mathrm{dom}}` as suggested by David. Any objections?

Comment: well if you want something that only works with dvips than you can shorten the code. But if you want something that works with both ways (or perhaps even more) then some overhead can not really be avoided. I wouldn't worry about it. glossaries puts so many macros into your document that one \mathrm more or less doesn't count.

Comment: Yes. And the time for a compilation (from a clean state, i.e., without any auxiliary files) of the book I edit is around 309 s till a stable (without dangling links, with proper bibliography, index, glossary, etc.) Postscript document is produced. The PDF file takes 290 s. The overhead of superfluous `\mathrm`s for each single compilation is tiny; the total overhead over months is probably considerable. I wonder whether `\newcommand{\domain}{\mathop{\gls{not:domain}}}` combined with `text={\mathrm{dom}}` would produce the required result for all four engines (pdflatex,latex, xetex,lualatex)?